# Присвоить переменной часть строки

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите, пожалуйста.
Есть строка:

```
INN6731111111.KPP672222222OOO mLAK CENTRm //214, SMOL OBL., G.SMOLENSK, UL. PO
```

как присвоить переменной значение `LAK CENTR`? от `[пробел]m`, до `m[пробел]//`

Answer (score 2):

Это хорошая возможность воспользоваться [регулярными выражениями](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Шаблон:  `m(.*)m //`

***Пример:***

```py
import re

s = 'INN6731111111.KPP672222222OOO mLAK CENTRm //214, SMOL OBL., G.SMOLENSK, UL. PO'

result = re.findall(' m(.*)m //', s)[0]
print(result)
```

***stdout:***

```py
LAK CENTR
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, нужно поближе познакомиться с регулярными выражениями)

Comment: Можно и строковыми методами:    print(s[s.find(' m') + 2: s.find('m ')])